# Construction of orthogonal matrices from orthogonal polynomials

Tags: inner-products, orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices, orthogonal-polynomials

Let $\{P_n\}_{0\le n\le N}$ be the family of orthogonal polynomials associated with the following inner product:
$$
\langle f, g \rangle_{1} = \sum_{k=0}^{N}{f(k)g(k)w_1(k)}
$$
where $ w_1(\cdot)$ is the weight function and $N$ is a non-negative integer.
Then, we can construct an orthogonal matrix $A = (a_{ij})_{0 \leq i, j \leq N}$ defined by
$$
a_{ij} = P_i(j)\sqrt{\frac{w(j)}{\|P_i\|_1^2}}\qquad \text{and} \qquad -1 \leq a_{ij} \leq 1
$$
Now, consider the following inner product:
$$
\langle f, g \rangle_{2} =\langle f, g \rangle_{1} + \sum_{k=0}^{N}{f'(k)g'(k)w_2(k)}
$$
where $w_2(\cdot)$ is the weight function and $f'$ denotes the derivative of $f$. Let $\{Q_n\}_{n}$ be a family of orthogonal polynomials associated with $\langle . \rangle_2$. My problem is how can I construct an orthogonal matrix $B=(b_{ij})_{0\le i,j\le N}$ such that $ -1 \leq b_{ij} \leq 1$.

Comment: The function $f$ is not uniquely determined by its values at $0,1,\ldots,N,$ unless you restrict to polynomials of degree less than or equal $N.$ Thus in general $ f'$ is not well defined, because it may occur that $f$ coincides with $g$ on $0,1,\ldots,N,$ but $f'$ and $g'$ do not coincide.

Comment: Thank you for your remark , I corrected the error

Comment: The absolute values of the entries of an orthogonal matrix are always $\le1$; that's not an additional constraint.